# Why no "the" or "a" here?

Tags: grammar, articles, zero-article

> I had asked the man in wardrobe to take a photo of me.

Why is it that there's no articles before the noun *wardrobe*?

Comment: Because it's [this guy](http://www.thestudiotour.com/fox/costume2.jpg) not [this guy](http://www.flickr.com/photos/24936330@N00/527098000/lightbox/)

Comment: So it means the man was in a closet full of clothes? It's the same grammar as " I went to school"??

Comment: No, it means the man works in the wardrobe department (for example in a movie studio)

Comment: I see. I also found a sentence like this. "She went to wardrobe for her fitting." In this case, she is a performer and wardrobe is a room right?

Comment: It's more than a room. Wardrobe, when used in relation to a theatrical or film studio, means the department responsible for costumes. When wardrobe is used without an article it implies a studio setting.

Comment: Shouldn't wardrobe used this way be a proper noun though? Like "I asked Mother" as opposed to "I asked my mother".

Comment: Some people might give it a capital for clarity, but it's really an abbreviation of 'the wardrobe department', just as you might refer to the finance department as 'finance'.

Comment: @FriendlyGreasemonkey: Can you post that as an *answer* please?

Comment: @alkenrinnstet "I asked Mother" is not opposed to "I asked my mother" since the first instance of mother is referring to the name you give her (which should be capitalised) and the second instance you're referring to the relationship you have with her (which should not be capitalised).

Comment: Not the relationship; the person.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more than a room. Wardrobe, when used in relation to a theatrical or film studio, means the department responsible for costumes. When wardrobe is used without an article it implies a studio setting.

Common expressions heard in studios include:

> "I need to get to wardrobe for my costume change."
>
> "I saw a beautiful outfit down in wardrobe."
>
> "Go to wardrobe and pick out some clothes that you like."

Comment: This holds for any department within any large organization, hence tropes like *meeting the new guy in accounting* or *let customer service handle it* or *we have a meeting with marketing at 2pm*.